# Copy Entire Table To Another Except For One Column In Oracle

Tags: oracle

In the following code I am trying to copy the contents of a table to another one except for one column. For that particular column, I want to insert a value from a third table where two columns from different tables match.

```
insert into PlaneKeyLookup (launchtime, landingtime, flightduration,
                 planeid, pilot1init, pilot2init, launchtype, kmsflown) values
((select launchtime from NewFlightsTransformed),
(select landingtime from NewFlightsTransformed),
(select flightduration from NewFlightsTransformed),
(select dp.id from D_Plane dp where exists
   (select nf.planeregistration from NewFlightsTransformed 
    where dp.registration = nf.planeregistration)),
(select pilot1init from NewFlightsTransformed),
(select pilot2init from NewFlightsTransformed),
(select launchtype from NewFlightsTransformed),
(select kmsflown from NewFlightsTransformed));
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL you want will be more like:

```
insert into PlaneKeyLookup (launchtime, landingtime, flightduration,
                 planeid, pilot1init, pilot2init, launchtype, kmsflown)
select launchtime, 
       landingtime, 
       flightduration,
       (select dp.id from D_Plane dp where...),
       pilot1init, 
       pilot2init, 
       launchtype, 
       kmsflown
  from NewFlightsTransformed;
```

I don't know exactly what the query for planeid should be, but it must return 1 row that gets the ID you wnat for the NewFlightsTransformed row it goes with.  It can be **correlated** with the outer query if required (probably):

```
(select dp.id from D_Plane dp 
  where dp.xxx = NewFlightsTransformed.xxx
    and ...)
```

Perhaps:

```
(select dp.id from D_Plane dp where dp.registration = nf.planeregistration)
```

i.e.

```
insert into PlaneKeyLookup (launchtime, landingtime, flightduration,
                 planeid, pilot1init, pilot2init, launchtype, kmsflown)
select launchtime, 
       landingtime, 
       flightduration,
       (select dp.id from D_Plane dp where dp.registration = nf.planeregistration),
       pilot1init, 
       pilot2init, 
       launchtype, 
       kmsflown
  from NewFlightsTransformed nf;
```

Comment: The select statement that I've come up with is this: select dp.id from D_Plane dp where exists (select nf.planeregistration from NewFlightsTransformed nf where dp.registration = nf.planeregistration). It workes if I execute it by itself, but with the insert statement, it shows a single-row subquery returns more than one row error. How is it supposed to be done properly?